# Deploying a Rails app to Heroku using SmartFile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have deployed a Rails app to Heroku but most of my images and text are stored using Postgres and are only accessible locally, so my app is incomplete. I've done a PG dump of my database and I have an account with Smartfile, but I'm not sure how to use Smartfile with Heroku. I just want my app to access my files right now. Have any of you used Smartfile in conjunction with Heroku? Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I decided not to use Smartfile and just used Heroku pg:push instead, as I don't think the app will be big enough to need more than the local database.